# Elastic Search Spring data Optimistic Concurrency Control

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

According to the `Elastic Search` `API` manual, it provides a mechanism to handle concurrency using [optimistic concurrency control](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/optimistic-concurrency-control.html).

The Elastic Search Java [API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-update-api.html) supports this feature through the

- `setVersion()`
- `setVersionType()`
- `setRetryOnConflict()`

methods in the `UpdateRequest` class.
Do we have any `API/configuration` in `Elastic Search Spring data` for performing the same operation?

The option I can think of is to override the `save()` method in the `ElasticSearchRepository` and provide a custom implementation.

Is there a better way to handle this before taking that route.

Versions used : `Elastic Search 1.3.2`, `Spring Data Elastic Search 1.1.0`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, on how to ask a good question. It helps your question gain more attention.

Comment: Hope this helps - The method `setUpdateRequest()`  in the class `UpdateQuery` and the method `withUpdateRequest()` in the class `UpdateQueryBuilder` take a `UpdateRequest` instance as its parameter, You can use it to  set the parameters to control the optimistic concurrency feature. - http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/query/UpdateQueryBuilder.html#withUpdateRequest-org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateRequest-